# Cant start docker container

Tags: docker, system

So basicly i copied [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/commonsearch/local-elasticsearch/) repo and i created my [own](https://hub.docker.com/r/outdream1337/local-elasticsearch/)( based on it )

Previously when i started commonsearch/elasticsearch container it worked perfecly, but after the copy outdream1337@elasticsearch container doesnt work any more. it produces no errors:

```
karlis@karlis-SATELLITE-L750 ~/Projects/search/cosr-back $ docker run -d -p 39200:9200 -p 39300:9300 outdream1337/local-elasticsearch
c2bc8fb75cb1df09ef4b87890fa1ec22760659aa4deed42c5f2cb89f3891bf60
dkarlis@karlis-SATELLITE-L750 ~/Projects/search/cosr-back $ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
karlis@karlis-SATELLITE-L750 ~/Projects/search/cosr-back $
```

and logs doesnt say anything ussfull too( because my other repo preduces same errors and everything works ):

```
time="2016-06-02T22:27:58.848821703+03:00" level=info msg="No non-localhost DNS nameservers are left in resolv.conf. Using default external servers : [nameserver 8.8.8.8 nameserver 8.8.4.4]" 
time="2016-06-02T22:27:58.848865787+03:00" level=info msg="IPv6 enabled; Adding default IPv6 external servers : [nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888 nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8844]"
```

ideas ?

Comment: start the container without the -d option and check if you can find a reason why it is crashing

Comment: Error logs are the same ;//

Comment: I got a clue, when i run a docker container, it is working for 1 second and then dies, why is that ?

Comment: @lvRRimUm can you share the changes you made to the image? What did you add in your Dockerfile? Without this information it may be hard to answer this.

Comment: I didnt not do any changes to image, i just copied it and saved. now trying to run.

Comment: Neither of the images have a shared dockerfile. Without the dockerfile its impossible to debug for anyone

Comment: How do you mean 'copy'? there is no dockerfile so it wasn't probably possible to build the image. You can just pull the exisiting image and tag it on your name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you didn't change the image (based on reading the comments). 
So as far as I understand you want the same image on your own name in your own repository. Than your able to perform this:
(this is what I did):

```
docker pull commonsearch/local-elasticsearch:latest
```

Tested the image:

```
docker run -d -p 39200:9200 -p 39300:9300 commonsearch/local-elasticsearch:latest
```

container is running, no errors:

```
4c5bae680145        commonsearch/local-elasticsearch:latest   "/docker-entrypoint.s"   36 seconds ago      Up 35 seconds       0.0.0.0:39200->9200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:39300->9300/tcp   stoic_lalande
```

Than you're able to tag the image on your own name:

```
docker tag commonsearch/local-elasticsearch:latest outdream1337/local-elasticsearch:latest
```

Test your image (which is actually just the same as the image of commonsearch). Don't forget to perform a `docker rm -fv containerID` on the container of commonsearch because this container is using the same ports as you want to use with your image:

```
docker run -d -p 39200:9200 -p 39300:9300 outdream1337/local-elasticsearch:latest

948a1361d99e        outdream1337/local-elasticsearch:latest   "/docker-entrypoint.s"   24 seconds ago       Up 23 seconds        0.0.0.0:39200->9200/tcp, 0.0.0.0:39300->9300/tcp   mad_kalam
```

Container keeps running. No errors. so Login in into docker hub:
`docker login` + credentials

```
docker push outdream1337/local-elasticsearch:latest
```

So now you have just the same image. Tagged on your own name in your own repository.